# Kotlin Flows and File IO

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a `Flow<FileChunk>` which I need to append into a File. My naive approach would be:

```
     File(fileame).bufferedWriter().use { writer ->
        withContext(IO) {
            requests.collect {
                writer.write(it.fileChunk.content.toStringUtf8())
            }
        }
    }
```

Unfortuntately, IntelliJ marks the "write" as "blocking". What is the right way of achieving what I want? Thanks!

Comment: I think your code is fine. This particular warning seems to have a lot of false positives. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-838

Answer (score 0):

You actually need a `CoroutineScope` to launch a `suspend` function. In this case I'd go with these two options:

1. Create or use an available coroutine scope. For ex:

```
 File(fileame).bufferedWriter().use { writer ->
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch{
            requests.collect {
                writer.write(it.fileChunk.content.toStringUtf8())
            }
        }
    }
```

2. Or if you're inside a function, you could make it a `suspend fun`, and handle the coroutine scope on the site of the function calling